# Mongo compatible with php 5.2.9

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, version

Which mongo version should I install in my ubuntu 16.04 LTS for php version 5.2.9 which has good support as well? 
Currently I'm using 3.2.

Comment: Please do consider upgrading PHP first, 5.2 is quite ancient and not supported for a long time now